# how to render X = <B, C, D, C, A, B, C> in HTML?

Tags: html

I have the following code in html page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
 <code>

  X = <B, C, D, C, A, B, C>
 and Y = <C, A, D, B, C, B>

 </code>
<pre>

   X = <B, C, D, C, A, B, C>
 and Y = <C, A, D, B, C, B>

 </pre>

   </body>
```

`

I Want the output as

```
  X = <B, C, D, C, A, B, C>
  and Y = <C, A, D, B, C, B>
```

but what I get is :

[image: required output]

Why is it rendering this way? what am i missing?

Comment: &lt; and &gt; instead of < > ?

Comment: isn't the pre and code tag supposed to care of that instead?

Comment: No, pre and code only care of newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `<` and `>` with their html entities:

```
<pre>
X = &lt;B, C, D, C, A, B, C&gt;
and Y = &lt;C, A, D, B, C, B&gt;
</pre>
```

becomes:

```
X = <B, C, D, C, A, B, C>
and Y = <C, A, D, B, C, B>
```